# SAS data balancing good & bad

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, proc

I have a data set where the %age of bads are quite low.Can any one suggest a way to balance such a data set using SAS so that the logistic regression run gives a better result? Below is a sample. Thanks in advance!!

```
ID  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  Target
 1  87  400 2   0   0   0
 2  70  620 1   0   0   0
 3  66  410 3   0   0   0
 4  85  300 1   0   0   0
 5  100 200 4   0   0   0
 6  201 110 1   0   0   0
 7  132 513 3   0   0   0
 8  98  417 4   0   0   0
 9  397 620 1   0   0   1
10  98  700 5   0   0   1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can oversample the percentage of bads and then use the `priorevent` option within the `score` statement of `proc logistic` to correct the oversampling.  There are plenty of examples online that will help you further with this.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Keith.I tried looking for something apt in the past few days but couldn't figure out as far as the oversampling is concerned so posted the question in order to find a way out.Would be great if you can suggest something? Thanks in advance